# What does yolov4.conv.137 mean in Yolov4 darknet?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I can't find a description of these weights used in tutorial for training [Yolov4 darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) and I can't really understand where they came from, COCO? PASCAL VOC? ImageNet?
I can't understand also if running the command `!./darknet detector train ./obj.data ./yolov4-obj.cfg ./yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map` means fine-tuning (i.e. simply initializing the model with weights without freezing anything) or transfer learning (freezing layers in the model)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are learned from MS COCO:  [ref](https://books.google.it/books?id=P1k7EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA693&lpg=PA693&dq=yolov4.conv.137++coco?&source=bl&ots=uhOdMJiYJS&sig=ACfU3U0YkU_aMLD9Pw6xy6RwXbBF6_CO-w&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj66tun25f0AhXLzqQKHd_aCocQ6AF6BAgSEAM#v=onepage&q=yolov4.conv.137%20%20coco%3F&f=false)